# is there any efficient way to solve the runtime error?

Tags: runtime

In competitive programming your code should be error free. The runtime error is common when you go for writing a code. So can anyone help me to find why this error occur.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one fix way to solve run time error. This is because runtime errors are caused by a bunch of reasons. Some common reasons are :

1. Division by zero.
2. Trying to access or modify Invalid or out of bounds array/vector/string index.
3. Very large memory allocation.
4. Data type mismatch errors

Most of these require you to correct them in different way through debugging process and checking your code. There's no fix one stop solution for it.